# Tracking effort and time spent on task for project management

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I would like to use org-mode for project management. With the `:Effort:` property, I can already track estimates of how much time a certain task will take, and displaying an `%Effort{:}` column is a great way of having an overview of the total effort.

Now I would like to track the progress on the task(s), i.e., the time spent on a task as reported by a team member. I could not find a similar tag like `:Completed:` or so. Ideally I would like to see, in column view, a percentage of how much of the task has already been completed, and what the remaining effort (and effort sum in a hierarchy of tasks) is. Is this possible? Would I need to "clock times" (although the precise times when a certain task was worked on by a team member are neither important to nor known by me), or is there a better approach?